# Spring Framework and encode/decode of public key

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, rsa

I am trying to create a new RsaVerifier to check a public key:

```
JwtHelper.decodeAndVerify(token, verifier);
```

I do believe it's a valid public key. I'm copying it correctly from my browser. It does begin with a return character though. It actually has them in several places:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBI.....
```

It fails when creating an RsaVerifier.

```
SignatureVerifier verifier = null;
if (key.startsWith("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----")) {
    logger.log("Trying to get key verifier...");
    verifier =  new RsaVerifier(key);  //FAILS HERE
    ...
```

Specifically, it's failing on the last line in this snippet from RsaKeyHelper:

```
private static Pattern PEM_DATA = Pattern.compile("-----BEGIN (.*)-----(.*)-----END (.*)-----", Pattern.DOTALL); 

static KeyPair parseKeyPair(String pemData) { 
  Matcher m = PEM_DATA.matcher(pemData.trim()); 

  if (!m.matches()) { 
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("String is not PEM encoded data"); 
  } 

  String type = m.group(1); 
  final byte[] content = b64Decode(utf8Encode(m.group(2)));  //FAILS HERE
```

with error:

```
Exception validating token : 
org.springframework.security.jwt.codec.InvalidBase64CharacterException: Bad 
Base64 input character decimal 92 in array position 0
```

I know decimal 92 is a forward slash and I have one in position 0, in fact. However, I've tried removing the return characters and it doesn't recognize it as valid. Here's a link to the RsaKeyHelper class:

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=spring-security-oauth-master/spring-security-jwt/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/jwt/crypto/sign/RsaKeyHelper.java
I am struggling to figure out how I can pass this key as a string that is accepted.

Comment: You say you believe your public key is valid, and you also say it has a forward slash in it. Well, if it has a forward slash in it, then guess what? That's right, it's not valid. Perhaps somehow you copied a representation of the key that has `\n` being displayed instead of an actual newline. Don't do that. The version you should be using has a newline, not a '\' followed by an 'n'.

Comment: Thanks. I am sure you are right and the \n is the problem but when I curl the URL for the token key I get that character. Do you have a suggestion on the best way to get the key without this character in it?   "value":"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0.....

Comment: I'm not completely certain where the problem is. Perhaps you can supply the actual location of the public key in question. If you are reluctant to do that then give another public location, e.g. https://www.example.com/, that you don't care about where the result is essentially the same

Comment: @Mike I've got the very same error. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Never did. I moved onto another project and have yet to get back to it. I'll watch this thread in case you are able to resolve it :)